# jquery validate on focus to show tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using the validate plugin but I am not sure how to make the error message appear when the form field first gets focus.

I would like to do this because the error message doubles up as a tooltip.

Once the field has run the validation once it works exactly how I would like it to (on keypress etc) but just not until the element first loses focus.

Here's my code...

```
<form>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="username" /><div class="tooltipContainer"></div>
</div>

</form>​
```

and

```
var validator = $("form").validate({ 

        rules: { 

            username: { 
                required: true, 
                minlength: 5, 
            }
        }, 
        messages: { 
            username: { 
                required:  "Required...", 
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters please..."), 
            }
        }, 

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            error.appendTo( element.next()); 
        }, 

        success: function(label) { 
            label.html(" ").addClass("checked"); 
        } 
    }); ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4dkr/

Comment: Does this help in some way:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165876/hook-jquery-validation-message-changes

Comment: It might, although I'm not sure how I'd implement it into my example.